# laravel with Mega cloud

Tags: laravel, upload, cloud, storage

I'm using openshift for laravel hosting. Now I want to upload files to my host, but there are two problems:

1. when I upload to openshift, over 30 sec, the connection is timed out.
2. when I use "git push" all the uploads file are removed.

Now I want to use cloud service for upload. I have problem with AWS :) ...
I'm searching and found [MEGA Cloud](http://mega.nz). Is there any way to upload on mega cloud from laravel storage?

What is the best way to upload files over 4MB size?

Comment: If you're looking for reliable object storage, AWS is definitely the way to go over MEGA. MEGA is basically just a cyberlocker, mostly used for piracy. It doesn't have an uptime SLA and it doesn't guarantee against data loss. Also, its client libraries are going to be worse than AWS. I suggest you instead face whatever particular issue you had with Amazon's S3 service, because over the long term you'll have much better success with it. Additionally, Laravel has almost out-of-the-box support for storing files on S3.

Comment: tanks... i know. but big problem is i`m in iran! and iran not supported in amazon... ok there is any way?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can use AWS's services from Iran, you'll just have to use the availability zone that's closest to you.

Comment: thanks :) for example afghanistan!